# Changing the year of a date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures

I am relatively new to programming. I have a table and in the table I have a column which shows when an employee started at the company. I am creating a procedure and within that procedure, I want to take the users start date and replace it with the current year, this will then be followed by an if statement. If the date that has just been calculated is before today, then change the year of the date to next year. Thanks and sorry if the question isn't fully clear or has been asked before.

Comment: You're thinking procedurally. What you want is to take a date and find the next occurrence of the anniversary of that date in the future. Don't say "I want to get the date adjusted to this year, *then* if that date is in the past, I want to add a year".

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the most elegant solution, but you could take the date apart to replace it with the current year. Then use a case statement to change it to the next year if it has already passed. Here's the code:

```
SELECT employee_name, 
    CASE
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DAY(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(getdate())) < GETDATE() THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DAY(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(getdate())+1)
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DAY(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(getdate())) >= GETDATE() THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DAY(start_date))+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(getdate()))
    END AS anniversary_date
FROM Employees
```

Comment: @Chris if this answer satisfies you, please award it the green tick so that your question is removed from the unanswered questions list.  If it isn't quite what you are looking for, please explain what needs to be improved with a comment on this answer so that april4181 or another user will know that this question is still seeking a solution.